# Posting JSON data using HttpClient

Tags: c#, json, httpclient, azure-devops

I am trying to create a service hook subscription in Visual Studio Team Services, previously Visual Studio Online, programatically. When a project is created in Team Services, service hook will be automatically created. Following is my code for 'workitem created' web hook:

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                        new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",
                       Convert.ToBase64String(
                           System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
                               string.Format("{0}:{1}", username, password))));

                    var request = new 
                    {
                        publisherId = "tfs",
                        eventType= " workitem.created",
                        resourceVersion= "1.0",
                        consumerId= "webHooks",
                        consumerActionId= "httpRequest",
                        publisherInputs= new {      
                            projectId= "test123",
                        }, 
                        consumerInputs= new {
                            url = "https://mydomain/api/ServiceHook/SaveWorkItem"
                        }
                    };


                    var response = client.PostAsync("https://mydomain/DefaultCollection/_apis/hooks/subscriptions",
                        new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request).ToString(),
                            Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))
                            .Result;

                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        dynamic content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(
                            response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
                            .Result);


                        // Access variables from the returned JSON object
                        var appHref = content.links.applications.href;
                    }
                }
```

while running this code, I got the following error: `Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '',`.

Can any one please help me to solve this?
Thanks in advance. 
Stack Trace is:

```
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ReadForType(JsonReader reader, JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value)
   at TestApplication.Program.<SetServiceHook>d__1.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\TestApplication\TestApplication\Program.cs:line 94
```

Comment: Post the stacktrace...

Comment: Verify your Json structure here: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: On which line are you getting the error?

Comment: The same question: On which line are you getting the error? I copied your code and did a quick test with it. The webhook can be created successfully. The only issue is "var appHref = content.links.applications.href;" since "links.applications.href" does not exist in the response message.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.. I got the error @ Deserializing

Comment: Can you try to write the output of "response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result" to check the response body first?

Comment: I got the  output of "response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result" as html. I googled it and it seems like prompting to sign in.

Answer (score 2):

Try below code-

```
var dataObjects = response1.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
var rootObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(dataObjects);
```

where **RootObject** is response object.

Comment: RootObject is class of your response. This is created based on response json format. You can use this link - http://json2csharp.com/.